# Python unittest mock: Is it possible to mock the value of a method's default arguments at test time?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have a method that accepts default arguments:

```
def build_url(endpoint, host=settings.DEFAULT_HOST):
    return '{}{}'.format(host, endpoint)
```

I have a test case that exercises this method:

```
class BuildUrlTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_build_url(self):
        """ If host and endpoint are supplied result should be 'host/endpoint' """

        result = build_url('/end', 'host')
        expected = 'host/end'

        self.assertEqual(result,expected)

     @patch('myapp.settings')
     def test_build_url_with_default(self, mock_settings):
        """ If only endpoint is supplied should default to settings"""
        mock_settings.DEFAULT_HOST = 'domain'

        result = build_url('/end')
        expected = 'domain/end'

        self.assertEqual(result,expected)
```

If I drop a debug point in `build_url` and inspect this attribute `settings.DEFAULT_HOST` returns the mocked value. However the test continues to fail and the assertion indicates `host` is assigned the value from my actual `settings.py`. I know this is because the `host` keyword argument is set at import time and my mock is not considered.

**debugger**

```
(Pdb) settings
<MagicMock name='settings' id='85761744'>                                                                                                                                                                                               
(Pdb) settings.DEFAULT_HOST
'domain'
(Pdb) host
'host-from-settings.com'
```

Is there a way to override this value at test time so that I can exercise the default path with a mocked `settings` object?

Comment: Make sure you are patching the correct instance of `myapp`. Where is `build_url` defined? You may need something like `@patch('module.myapp.settings')` rather than `@patch(myapp.settings)`.

Comment: Yep, a quick of settings in the debugger shows that it is being patched correctly(`settings = <magicmock blah blah`). I surmise that `host=settings.DEFAULT_HOST` happens before the patch.

Comment: Oh, right. The default is set when the function is defined (the same reason `def foo(x=[])` doesn't give you a fresh empty list every time you call `foo()`). Which leads to a possible answer...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Functions store their parameter default values in the `func_defaults` attribute when the function is defined, so you can patch that. Something like

```
def test_build_url(self):
    """ If only endpoint is supplied should default to settings"""

    # Use `func_defaults` in Python2.x and `__defaults__` in Python3.x.
    with patch.object(build_url, 'func_defaults', ('domain',)):
      result = build_url('/end')
      expected = 'domain/end'

    self.assertEqual(result,expected)
```

I use `patch.object` as a context manager rather than a decorator to avoid the unnecessary patch object being passed as an argument to `test_build_url`.

Comment: Will this replace `build_url` with a `Mock`? That is the method I want to test.

Comment: Whoops never mind. Worked like a champ! Quick edit you don't want to patch the string `'build_url'` rather the assigned variable.

Comment: This answer looked great at first but tripped me up for the reason listed in the answer by [Jeff O'Neill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42179486/496445)

Comment: Oh! That's so close to what I was looking for. Anyone know how you can do similar with the `__init__` method? Similar to @nsfyn55 I want to change a default value but from the constructor :-/ I tried @chepner cleaver trick but I think It can't be done on a static method.

Comment: When I try to use a path instead of a function, `@patch.object('some_module.my_function', '__defaults__', (22,))` I get `AttributeError: some_model.my_function does not have the attribute '__defaults__'`

Comment: `patch.object` takes a reference to the actual object, not a qualified name as a `str`, as the first argument.  `@patch.object(some_module.my_function, '__defaults__', (22,))`.

Comment: @chepner what if I want to patch the default arguments of a function that is imported in the function that I'm testing? I'm testing a function `my_module.main_function` which also defines a `my_module._minor_function` and I want to change the default arguments of `_minor_function` but use `main_function` in my test. The test is in a separate file of course.

Comment: Please post a new question where you can show your use case more clearly.

Comment: @chepner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728285/how-do-i-mock-the-default-arguments-of-a-function-that-is-used-by-the-function-i

Answer (score 8):

An alternate way to do this: Use functools.partial to provide the "default" args you want. This isn't *technically* the same thing as overriding them; the call-ee sees an explicit arg, but the call-er doesn't have to provide it. That's close enough most of the time, and it does the Right Thing after the context manager exits:

```
# mymodule.py
def myfunction(arg=17):
    return arg

# test_mymodule.py
from functools import partial
from mock import patch

import mymodule

class TestMyModule(TestCase):
    def test_myfunc(self):
        patched = partial(mymodule.myfunction, arg=23)
        with patch('mymodule.myfunction', patched):
            self.assertEqual(23, mymodule.myfunction())  # Passes; default overridden
        self.assertEqual(17, mymodule.myfunction()) # Also passes; original default restored
```

I use this for overriding default config file locations when testing. Credit where due, I got the idea from Danilo Bargen [here](https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2016/2/18/overriding_default_arguments_in_pytest/)

Comment: I'm not sure this covers my core use case. I am looking to test that this function works as expected with a default parameter vs. a provided kwarg. If I just simulate providing the `kwarg`its not really producing anything of value.  I could just create a test that supplies `arg=23` and achieve the same net effect.

Comment: This is pretty nifty.

Comment: I prefer this answer to the others: `__defaults__` is bound to change as the signature of the function changes and it can be easy to miss that. Also, the code is more obvious in this answer.

Answer (score 7):

I applied the other answer to this question, but after the context manager, the patched function was not the same as before.

My patched function looks like this:

```
def f(foo=True):
    pass
```

In my test, I did this:

```
with patch.object(f, 'func_defaults', (False,)):
```

When calling `f` after (not in) the context manager, the default was completely gone rather than going back to the previous value.  Calling `f` without arguments gave the error `TypeError: f() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

Instead, I just did this before my test:

```
f.func_defaults = (False,)
```

And this after my test:

```
f.func_defaults = (True,)
```

Comment: Had a similar issue, thanks for posting! Would you say this is a bug? Seems odd the defaults are returned to the original?