# How do I mock the default arguments of a function that is used by the function I'm testing?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have this `my_module.py`:

```py
def _sub_function(do_the_thing=True):
    if do_the_thing:
        do_stuff()
    else:
        do_something_else()


def main_function():
    # do some stuff
    if some_condition:
        return _sub_function()
    else:
        return _sub_function(do_the_thing=False)
```

then I have this test, `test_my_module.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import my_module


class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch.object("my_module._sub_function", "__defaults__", (False,))
    def test_main_function(self):
        print(my_module.main_function())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I have a function `_sub_function` that takes a default argument that decides if it performs some steps or not. Normally, `main_function` calculates when those actions need to be performed and overrides that default argument. Unfortunately, when running tests I can't perform those actions when I normally need to.

So my idea was to use a default argument on `_sub_function` and in my test to patch the function to monkey-patch that argument to be `False` so that it skips these actions during testing. Unfortunately I can't use the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021491) because I'm testing `main_function`, and not `_sub_function`, so I don't have `_sub_function` in my test. `mock.patch.object` can only take the object being patched as an argument, not a string containing the import path of the object (like `mock.patch` does), so the above code doesn't work, it raises an `AttributeError: my_module._sub_function does not have the attribute '__defaults__'` on the `mock.patch.object()` line.

Is there a way to patch a functions default arguments using the string import path of that function.

Or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Do you have control over `main_function`? It seems like `return _sub_function(do_the_thing=some_condition)` would make more sense than making two calls, one of which relies on a default value that you are already assuming is `True`.

Comment: @chepner my real code has 3 different cases and `_sub_function` takes other arguments that are also different depending on the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem is you are trying to patch an attribute of a `str` object, not your function:

```
class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch.object(my_module._sub_function, "__defaults__", (False,))
    def test_main_function(self):
        print(my_module.main_function())
```

The `AttributeError` being raised doesn't make that clear, unfortunately.

Comment: I imported `_sub_function` directly, like `from top_module.sub_module.my_module import _sub_function` and then passed that object to `patch.object`. Which in hindsight makes perfect sense that it would be that easy. I thought the object would be different if I import it in the test and in the module I'm testing.

Comment: I think the code will be more clear if I mock `_sub_function` with a function that calls it with that argument set to `False` always.

Comment: This does not work for class methods.