# How to mock the default value of a method in python?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have one class with a method that instantiates an element of a second class:

```
class FirstClass:

    def method_one():
        second_class = SecondClass()
```

the second class has a method with a default argument:

```
class SecondClass:
    def method_two(important_date: datetime.date = get_today())
```

and a function `get_today` in a different file `date_service`:

```
def get_today() -> datetime.date:
    return datetime.date.today()
```

I am testing `method_one` in a `test_first_class.py` and I don't manage to mock the value of `get_today()`.

I looked at several pages and solutions in SO and I couldn't fix it. Some of the ideas:

- I tried [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022444/11241615) but in the line

```
with patch.object(build_url, 'func_defaults', ('domain',)):
```

I don't know what I have to put at `build_url`. I tried something like `SecondClass.method_two` and it doesn't work.

REMARK: I know that a good unit test should test `FirstClass` and `SecondClass` independently, and mock `method_two` in `test_first_class.py` but for some reasons I can't do that :-(

Comment: Your program might give undesirable results if it runs through midnight.

Comment: In my case it's not a big deal, but I understand what you mean. Which would be a solution? If it runs through midnight, there is not way to avoid potential undesirable results, is there?

Comment: Have you tried understanding the doc ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object (not an expert in unitesting)

Comment: Instead of getting the day one as am argument default, use `None` as the default and handle it in the method to always get the recent day.

Comment: Oh @Klaus D., you are right! I hadn't considered the fact that default arguments are loaded only once! Ok, I'll change it and I won't need then to mock it that way. Still, I found a solution and I'll post it in case anyone is interested. Thank you very much for your remark!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem doing the following:

```
@staticmethod
@patch('date_service.get_today', Mock(return_value=mock_today))
def test_something():
    importlib.reload(second_class)
    importlib.reload(first_class)
    first_class_element = FirstClass()
    whatever = first_class_element.method_one()
    assert (...)
```

where `second_class` and `first_class` contain `SecondClass` and `FirstClass`, respectively; and mock_today is the date I use to mock today.

Attention: you need to reload BOTH classes, and in this very order, otherwise, it doesn't work.

Remark: as per @Klaus D. comment, I finally couldn't use `get_today()` as a default optional argument and I didn't have to use all this mess, but I give the answer in case anyone needs it...